# Swift: '()' is not convertible to '[String : AnyObject]'

Tags: ios, dictionary, swift

I added a custom `extension` to be able combine two `dictionaries` but having trouble with my method calling this new extension.

**Dictionary extension defined in AppDelegate**

```
extension Dictionary {
    mutating func merge<K, V>(dict: [K: V]){
        for (k, v) in dict {
            self.updateValue(v as Value, forKey: k as Key)
        }
    }
}
```

**Method using this new extension**

```
class func addFbTokenParameter(json: [String: AnyObject]) -> [String: AnyObject] {
    if KeychainManager.getString(KeychainManager.StaticVars.kFbToken) != nil {
        let token = KeychainManager.getString(KeychainManager.StaticVars.kFbToken)!

        var tokenParams: [String: AnyObject] = [
            kFacebook: [
                kToken: token
            ]
        ]

        var finalParams: [String: AnyObject] = tokenParams.merge(json)
        return finalParams
    }
    else {
        return json
    }
}
```

I am getting this error on this line:

```
var finalParams: [String: AnyObject] = tokenParams.merge(json)
```

What does this error mean? And how do I correct it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tokenParams.merge(json)` is returning `Void` aka `()`.
You can simply fix this code by:

```
tokenParams.merge(json)
var finalParams: [String: AnyObject] = tokenParams
```

Your extension need to return the mutated dictionary to be assignable:

```
extension Dictionary {
    mutating func merge<K, V>(dict: [K: V]) -> [K: V] {
        for (k, v) in dict {
            self.updateValue(v as Value, forKey: k as Key)
        }

        return self
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining. Works perfectly. Wasn't aware values could be changed and be able to keep the state of it without assigning it to a variable.